# Calculate dot product between two dictionaries millions of times

Tags: python-3.x, bigdata

I have two dictionaries d1 = {'string1': number1, ..., 'string5 000 000': number5000000} which does not change and many small dictionaries d_i = {'str1': num1, ..., 'str50': num50} (i = 2, 3, ..., a few million). I want to do a dot product between these dictionaries i.e. for every key in dictionary d_i that exists also in d_1 I would like their numbers multiplied and then added to the sum. 
The problem is that first dictionary is extremely big and there are millions of small dictionaries. 
How do I do that fast? Can I use some big data techniques for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data to pandas dataframe and then do dot product between series in dataframe. It can be faster but in you case I would measure how much time it takes in case of python implementation and pandas.

Comment: You should show a small code sample of how to achieve this as well.